# Reset column index in Pandas to 0,1,2,3...?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go about resetting the index of my dataframe columns to 0,1,2,3,4?

(How come doing `df.reset_index()` doesn't reset the column index?)

```
>>> data = data.drop(data.columns[[1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]], axis=1)
>>> data = data.drop(data.index[[0,1]],axis = 0)
>>> print(data.head())
             0         2    3    4    20
2  500292014600       .00  .00  .00  NaN
3  500292014600    100.00  .00  .00  NaN
4  500292014600  11202.00  .00  .00  NaN
>>> data = data.reset_index(drop = True)
>>> print(data.head())
              0         2    3    4    20
 0  500292014600       .00  .00  .00  NaN
 1  500292014600    100.00  .00  .00  NaN
 2  500292014600  11202.00  .00  .00  NaN
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try replacing the column names:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> my_data = [[500292014600, .00, .00, .00, np.nan],
              [500292014600, 100.00, .00, .00, np.nan], 
              [500292014600, 11202.00, .00, .00, np.nan]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=[0,2,3,4,20])
>>> df
              0        2    3    4  20
0  500292014600      0.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
1  500292014600    100.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
2  500292014600  11202.0  0.0  0.0 NaN

>>> df.columns = range(df.columns.size)
>>> df
              0        1    2    3   4
0  500292014600      0.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
1  500292014600    100.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
2  500292014600  11202.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 49):

**Warning: This method has serious potential side effects and should probably not be used - see comments!**

Try the following:

```
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
```

Comment: this sounds like a hack; the `reset_index` method should be possibly applied to column indexes as well

Comment: That's a nice way around the problem but is there a direct way to reset both row and column index?

Comment: Another downside that is not mentioned is that transposing messes up the dtypes. For example `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': list('ABC')})` will have int64/object, but `df.T.T` will have all objects. Also, transposing can be expensive.

Answer (score 4):

In pandas, by index you essentially mean row index. As you can see in your data, the row index is reset after drop and reset_index().

For columns, you need to rename them, you can do something like

```
data.columns = [ 0,1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize there is no answer that can easily be used in a pipeline/[method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html) (except the double transpose, but this is a waste of computing in my opinion and has the downside of messing up the dtypes).

One can use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df.set_axis(range(df.shape[1]), axis=1)
```

Used with [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for method chaining:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame('x', columns=list('ABCD'), index=range(2))
        .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(range(d.shape[1]), axis=1))
     )
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy imported with `import numpy as np`

simply set the columns to zero based indexes with `data.columns = [np.arange(0,data.shape[1])]`

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Python Implementation

We `enumerate` the `columns` of the dataframe to create an array of items. Then we `map` the function `reversed` to each item in the array. Lastly, we create and input the dictionary as the parameter `columns` in the data frame object method `rename`.

```
columns = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(df.columns)))
df = df.rename(columns=columns)
df.head()
```

**Results:**

```
              0        1    2    3   4
0  500292014600      0.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
1  500292014600    100.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
2  500292014600  11202.0  0.0  0.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

> How come when i use df.reset_index the index of my columns is not reset?

The column "index" is really more of a column title. It's possible that someone may using the "index" as a meaningful title. For example, perhaps they represent "Trial 1", "Trial 2", etc., so you wouldn't want to re-index it automatically and lose the significance.

> How do I go about resetting this index to 0,1,2,3,4?

To reset the column indexes:

```py
df.columns = range(df.columns.size)
```