# Reset column index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to reset columns so they becomes first row of `DataFrame`. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Desired ouput,

```
df2 = df.reset_column() ???
   0  1
0  a  b
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset column index in Pandas to 0,1,2,3...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284617/reset-column-index-in-pandas-to-0-1-2-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
In [57]: pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df]))
Out[57]:
   0  1
0  a  b
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

Answer (score 8):

Can also chain `reset.index`

```
df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)

    0   1
0   a   b
1   1   4
2   2   5
3   3   6
```

Comment: I didn't want to preserve the column headers, so did: `df.reset_index(drop=True).T.reset_index(drop=True).T`

Answer (score 1):

Inserting column names at the first row and resetting the indices.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

df.loc[-1] = df.columns
df.index = df.index + 1
df = df.sort_index()
df.columns = [0,1]
df

    0   1
0   a   b
1   1   4
2   2   5
3   3   6
```

Comment: It does overwrite the first row (`[1, 4]`) with column names.

Comment: @taras fixed, look at the updated answer. Thanks for info.